Equivalent of ORACLE signature with bind variable IN PostgreSQL
I am in the process of migrating from Oracle to Postgres with Ora2pg but I find this problem that the signatures on the Postgres side do not exist
can you help me find the right solution ?
What will be equivalent of following oracle's query in Postgres?
procedure evtAfterEachRow (INSERTING in boolean, UPDATING in boolean, DELETING in boolean, key in pkg_mouvement_calcul_cmn.rec_key, old in mouvement_calcul%rowtype, new in mouvement_calcul%rowtype, recTab in out rec_tab) is
    rowData             mouvement_calcul%rowtype;
    varSql              clob;
    varActionType       varchar2(1);
    varLoadDate         date;
    varSqlSignature     varchar2(4000) ;
    n number;
    logContext          varchar2(4000) ;
begin
    ref_2_addedData := recTab.ADDED_DATA; -- reference used by pl-sql injections into dynamic query
    if not (
        -- Extraction conditions:
        TRUE -- (see dynamic query)
    ) then return; end if;
    rowData := case when DELETING then old else new end;
    varActionType := case when DELETING then 'D' else 'I' end;
    varLoadDate := SYSDATE;

    logContext := 'PKG_MOUVEMENT_CALCUL.evtAfterEachRow';
    varSql := getLogSqlForMOVKF('MOUVEMENT_CALCUL', 1, varSqlSignature);
    case
        when varSqlSignature = '1239678541' then 
            execute immediate varSql using 
                 /*1*/rowData.CODE_MOUVEMENT        ,/*2*/rowData.TYPE_CALCUL           ,/*3*/rowData.MONTANT_CALCUL
                ,/*9*/rowData.MONTANT_CALCUL_DV     ,/*6*/rowData.DATE_CALCUL           ,/*7*/rowData.CHAINE_CALCUL
                ,/*8*/rowData.RESULTAT_CALCUL       ,/*5*/varActionType                 ,/*4*/varLoadDate       
                ,/*1*/rowData.CODE_MOUVEMENT
            ;
        else
            dk.throw(logContext||': Unhandled sql signature "'||varSqlSignature||'".');
    end case;
    if sql%rowcount = 0 and varActionType = 'D' then
        varSql := getLogSqlForMOVKF('MC/MOV_ALREADY_DELETED', 1, varSqlSignature);
        case
            when varSqlSignature = '412' then 
                execute immediate varSql using 
                     /*4*/varLoadDate               ,/*1*/rowData.CODE_MOUVEMENT        ,/*2*/rowData.TYPE_CALCUL
                ;
            else
                dk.throw(logContext||': Unhandled sql signature (D) "'||varSqlSignature||'".');
        end case;
        n := sql%rowcount;
        syn_hdl.trace(trLvl, syn_hdl.DEBUG, 0, pkg_mouvement_calcul_cmn.labelKey(key)||': '||chr(10)||'MC/MOV_ALREADY_DELETED: sql%rowcount == '||n, logContext);
    end if;
    recTab.ADDED_DATA := ref_2_addedData; -- updating ADDED_DATA for next trigger event executions
exception when others then
    pkg_trg.legacyTrgHandler(INSERTING, UPDATING, DELETING, logContext, null, pkg_mouvement_calcul_cmn.labelKey(key), null);
end;


As a PostgreSQL DBA without a lot of Oracle experience, I have no idea what this should do or what problem it should solve. And I'm mostly interested in the problem you try to solve.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78662741/equivalent-of-oracle-signature-in-postgresql

The code you have presented has invalid syntax in Oracle.

It starts with a CASE expression which has the syntax:
CASE WHEN expression THEN expression END

Your statement has CASE, WHEN and THEN but no expression after the THEN (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is not an expression) and no END keyword;

A CASE expression is not, on its own, a valid SQL or PL/SQL statement;

Then the code goes into what should be a separate PL/SQL statement to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE some dynamic SQL passing some bind variables from a record and should have a ; before the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to separate it from the previous statement.

A PL/SQL statement should be included in a DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END; block but this is not.

The variables varSqlSignature, varSql and rowData have not been declared and so we have no idea what what dynamic code would do or what the record contains as it is not included in the question.


Therefore, since the statement is invalid in Oracle due to multiple reasons then the equivalent in PostgreSQL would be another invalid statement (or even the same statement).

thank you for your answer, but I just put the necessary part of code without DECLARE, BEGIN and END because I like to see essentially the equivalent of the signatures on the postgres side

@aab Do not post code in comments as it is difficult to read; instead, edit your question and include it there (using appropriate formatting).

i edit the post, thanx for this information

The code you are showing must be PL/SQL, not SQL.
The incomplete code snippet you are showing would work just fine in PostgreSQL's PL/pgSQL procedural language if you remove the IMMEDIATE keyword (which is just noise anyway).
